# Disable keyboard when edittext changes programmatically

Tags: android

I'm making a numberpicker with a plus and minus button and an edittext.

When the user clicks the plus button, the text in the edittext should change, and 
if the user clicks on the edittext a keyboard should appear.

On my galaxy gio (android 2.3.6) everything works fine, but on my galaxy tab 10.1 (android 3.0) the keyboard pops up everytime I click on the plus or minus button.

So in short, I want to disable the keyboard when the edittext is changed programmatically, but when the user clicks the edittext, I want the keyboard to show up.

Any ideas?

Edit : I cannot use XML attributes, only java please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in you plus and minus button to hide soft Key Board

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                Youredittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

And this to show edit text by setting edit text click listner and in that click listner use following code

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```